# Disconnect (or Close) device connection if no message receive for a duration

Tags: azure-iot-hub

In my application, we have devices which connects with Azure IoTHub. Is there a way in IoTHub which enforce device disconnection if no message received from a device for a duration of 15 minutes ? Is there any such functionality present in Azure IotHub out of the box ?

Comment: There is no such this feature built-in the Azure IoT Hub. What kind of the protocol is used  for connection of the devices to the Azure IoT Hub? Are you using a device twins, device re-connection feature, cloud-to-device messaging, device direct methods, etc.? In the case of using only a telemetry data, you can consider to use a connection less oriented protocol such as the https.

Comment: Duplicate: [Microsoft Azure IoT Protocol Gateway - Disconnect Device if no message receive for a duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517098/microsoft-azure-iot-protocol-gateway-disconnect-device-if-no-message-receive-f)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such feature available in Azure IoTHub.

You can manage it programmatically. You can keep the device in sleep mode when there is no action on device side.

You can post a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python, you can use get_invoke_cli package to call cli

> az iot hub device-identity update --resource-group {resource-group} --hub-name {Hub} --device-id {device id} --sta disabled

to disable your iotdevice to connect to iothub